# Is it possible to open or launch a lightning experience app using URL?

Tags: lightning-experience

I am working on an existing application built on classic VF framework. It's pure custom application where header is hidden, there is one hyperlink which opens Lightning experience dashboard in new window.

1. Right now I am redirecting user to the dashboard page URL.Is it
   possible to open a particular lightning app (application built using LEX app manager) using URL? I can't make
   LEX app as default in profile otherwise they will get redirect to
   LEX after every login.
2. In Lightning experience I need to introduce a custom link which opens a new window or redirect user to the previous application.  Is
   it possible to introduce a custom link or custom component at header
   level so that user can go back to the previous application?

Are there any workarounds available for above issues in Salesforce?

Comment: It is possible to open a lightning App using an absolute/complete URL as `https://yourdomain-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/lightningApp.app`.
I had an anchor tag with href param set to this value in a visual force page which will redirect to a specific lightning App.

Comment: Hi Sikha, I was referring LEX application not the standalone lightning app. Let me update my question.